# How to redirect to new url, passing on old url, without session or query-string

Tags: http, redirect, design-patterns

The main key-feature I want here is the *you were redirected from "old-url.html"*

Check at what Wikipedia does when taking me to a canonical url of an article (which is exactly what I want to do):

[image]

Notice in the screenshot that I accessed **old-url.html** (united states of america article) but I was *redirected* to **new-url.html** (united states article), however, they didn't use any method for redirecting that I know of.

There are 3 main ways that I know how to redirect from **old-url.html** to **new-url.html** and let **new-url-html** know what was the **old-url.html**:

1. store the old url in session, then redirect to **new-url.html** and there (with php for example) check if `$_SESSION["redirected-from"]` exists
2. redirect to **new-url.html?redirected-from=old-url.html** (but with an ugly url)
3. just *update* the `document.title` property and perhaps make a `window.history.replaceState(...)` to make it look like I redirected the request.

But none of those solutions look like what wikipedia did right there. Now, I can continue to try to hack my way through this requirement, or... I could **ask the internet about perhaps a *common http pattern* that I could be unaware of**...

Thanks in advance for your help :-)

Comment: I kinda feel its more of a canonical URL thing

Comment: Why do you think Wiki is unusual? Looks like you ask for United_States_of_America but instead Wiki just serves up a modified version of United_States and updates the URL bar to United_States. After that an F5 refresh serves the unmodified United_States page. Note United_States_of_America, ASOA and other abbreviations listed are all real pages. Maybe I am going to learn more than you from your answer!

Comment: My question is, how did they do that? I want to do th same thing in my website but I don't know how _they_ do it